# How do I set a cookie for an integration test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, integration-testing

I have general application behavior that changes based on cookie contents, and need to test it. As an example, if a user doesn't have a cookie set indicating that they've accepted the site's legal terms, they need to be redirected to the T&C page.

I can set a cookie in a functional test using

```
request.cookies["legal_accepted"] = "yes"
```

However, this will not work in an integration test- there's no request object to work with. I've been unable to find any documentation of why this is so, what else is different, and best practices for working with the difference. How can I set a cookie for a given request? Is the why and wherefore documented anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Rails 5 integration tests metkat's answer should be altered slightly:

```
get "/", headers: {"HTTP_COOKIE" => "legal_accepted=yes; cookie2=value2;"}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 3.2.x (certainly in 3.2.16) you can assign the cookies directly in an integration test:

```
cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
```

You can now access the cookie 'foo' in your test and application:

```
puts cookies['foo']  (returns 'bar')
```

Comment: What testing framework were you using? I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: This works with minitest in Rails 5 (see `Rack::Test::CookieJar`)

Comment: Still works in Rails 7.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I have found to do this is to set the cookie header manually in the request, e.g.

```
get "/", {}, { "HTTP_COOKIE" => "legal_accepted=yes; cookie2=value2; "}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Poltergeist there are some methods for handeling cookies that I've used in integration tests.

https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#manipulating-cookies

One thing to note is that if you want to update a cookie, you'll have remove the cookie first, then set it.

```
page.driver.remove_cookie("cookie_name")
page.driver.set_cookie("cookie_name", "some_value")
```

Comment: The question asked about Rails integration tests, not Poltergeist-based full stack tests.